# google reverse geocoding api without google maps

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the geonames database but I need to get the postal code based on latitutde and longitude , geonames.org has such a service but the data is not accurate.
Google api reverse geocoding offers a more accurate data regarding postal codes.
Is it right that google geocoding api must be used with google maps, or can I use this google reverse geocoding api without displaying results on a map.

If not, does anyone know any other solutions other than geonames postal codes service in order to get the postal code based on lat. lng. ?

I want to copy and insert this postal codes into my geonames database.

I don't want to display the results on a map.

Comment: You're right: [the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues not programming

Comment: I found this on the Google api site for geocoding: You can display Geocoding API results on a Google Map, or without a map. If you want to display Geocoding API results on a map, then these results must be displayed on a Google Map. It is prohibited to use Geocoding API data on a map that is not a Google map. Link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/policies

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  As per Google [**API Terms of Service License Restrictions**](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12) it is prohibited.

- I would prefer to use [MapQuest **Open Geocoding** API Web
  Service](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/geocoding-service), which provides both geocoding and reverse geocoding.  They are licensed under the [Open Data Commons Open Database License (ODbL)](http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/).
- [Address
  Processing](http://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/AddressProcessing/Default.aspx),
  here you can find more free services.

Hope you got some idea.

Comment: The specific point in the Google API Terms of Service prohibiting use without a Google Map is 10.1.1(g)

Comment: It seems they have special rules for Premium accounts, as for free it's indeed prohibited due to their terms.